# Workbench crashed while exporting data

Tags: mysql

After clicking export into CSV. The workbench becomes not responding. How to solve this issue. Am a beginner so dont know much about SQL workbench. Can someone help me. Every time am closing and opening the workbench.

Comment: Welcome to SO. - You have to give some more detail. Is there an error message? Version of MySQL-Workbench? ...

Comment: Mysql Workbench version 8.0.25 community. No its not showing any error message. after clicking export. It becomes Not responding. Have waited also but no use. Have to close and reopen it. My laptop has enough space too. Thanks Andy

Comment: I am also experiencing the same problem with large result sets i.e. when the data is 20 MB or more. Have you found a solution yet? Meanwhile I am exploring internet and documentations.